# Fluent NHibernate: mapping one-to-one

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

NHibernate seems to support a special case of one to one mapping (That doesn't require a 1-m mapping on each side of the relationship).

See this article by Ayende:

http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/04/18/nhibernate-mapping-lt-one-to-one-gt.html

I have no idea how to specify this in *Fluent* NHibernate though - is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, just found from a helpful person in the Fluent group that I can use

```
HasOne(x => x.Cover);
```

Missed it somehow before :/

Answer (score 0):

One scenario is with subclasses.  You can specific a table per hierarchy or per class.

You would need to override for the per hierarchy something like below:

```
 public class UserMap : IAutoMappingOverride<User>
    {
        public void Override(AutoMapping<User> mapping)
        {
            mapping.DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn<int>("UserType");

        }
    }

        public void Override(AutoMapping<Person> mapping)
        {
            mapping.Table("Persons");

            DiscriminatorValue((int)UserTypes.Person);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping there would be a less complicated way of doing it :) I guess this would mean that there would have to be an inheritance relationship between the two objects though?  I don't really want to do that.